# Git add . error in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application and I'm having difficulties deploying it. When I issue the command `git add .`, the following error occurs:

```
git : error: open(".vs/DonationSite/FileContentIndex/56f14db3-4306-4df1-bad7-f487ea83802a.vsidx"): Permission denied
At line:1 character:1
+ git add .
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (error: open(".v...rmission denied:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

error: unable to index file 
'.vs/DonationSite/FileContentIndex/56f14db3-4306-4df1-bad7-f487ea83802a.vsidx'
fatal: adding files failed
```

I've already tried moving the `.gitignore` to the root folder, but it didn't work

Comment: Do you have the `.vs` folder excluded in your `.gitignore`?

Comment: @stuartd, hey! I added it, but it didn't work either. :(

Comment: Type `git status` or use another GUI to preview what files would be added if you were to commit your changes. The `.vs` folder should not be committed. You can use this as your base for the gitignore https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: The `.vs` folder contains generated content that is specific to you, which the current instance of Visual Studio may have locked for exclusive access. I'd ignore it, and remove it from your git repo.

Comment: Once files are already tracked, put them or containing folder in `.gitignore` is not enough : you have to untrack them.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to push the Code from the below folder

[image]

you will get this issue.

```cs
error: open(".vs/GitPush/FileContentIndex/c1f9f8f4-a85c-479e-a361-e9906066bc97.vsidx"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file '.vs/GitPush/FileContentIndex/c1f9f8f4-a85c-479e-a361-e9906066bc97.vsidx'
fatal: adding files failed
```

- Open the `.vs` => `GitPush` => `FileContentIndex` folder, you will find a file with `.vsidx` extension.

[image]

- Close the App which is opened in Visual Studio.
- Delete that file.

[image]

- Now run the command `git add .` .

```cs
C:\Users\****\source\repos\GitPush>git add .
warning: in the working copy of 'GitPush/Content/bootstrap-grid.css', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'GitPush/Content/bootstrap-grid.min.css', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'GitPush/Content/bootstrap-grid.rtl.css', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'GitPush/Content/bootstrap-grid.rtl.min.css', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'GitPush/Content/bootstrap-reboot.css', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
```

- Run the below commands to complete the task.

```cs
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "Commit after add"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/RepoName/GitHubRepo.git
git push -u origin main
```

```cs
Enumerating objects: 336, done.
Counting objects: 100% (336/336), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (315/315), done.
Writing objects: 100% (336/336), 37.10 MiB | 6.52 MiB/s, done.
Total 336 (delta 99), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (99/99), done.
To https://github.com/Harshitha/GitHubRepo.git
 * [new branch]      main -> main
branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'.
```

[image]